# What is a resource book?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself Networking in 24 Hours, 4th Edition by Uyless Black (2009)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0768685761)

Example:

> You should try to make room in your network budget for the purchase of **resource books**. Or, as a last resort, you need to spend some of your own hard-earned cash and take some time to read. The fact that you’ve become the greatest Novell NetWare guru on the planet will do you little good if your company decides to migrate to the Microsoft networking platform.

What are those exactly and why do we call them recourse books?

Comment: **resource book** is not a set phrase.  The noun **resource** is being used as an adjective, as English allows.  Put the two ideas of **resource** and **book** together, and you'll understand as well as the author does what he means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Resource books* are just books containing useful information about a particular subject. Dictionaries are one kind of resource book, as are atlases. In the context of your quotation, the term probably refers to computer hardware and software manuals.